# Throttle Linkage for Kohler Command 18 Engine in Cub Cadet 2186

Tags: small-engine, lawnmower

I pulled apart my engine and now can not figure out how to **connect my engine controls**.

**Update:** I did eventually get the bushing (#22) and rod (#23) to fit in the large hole by putting the bushing in first, and then pressing the rod through as well.

The reason there was no movement on the governor arm when I adjusted the throttle was indeed because "that's how a governor works" ... the engine has to be running in order for the mechanics within the engine to spin and cause counter-force.

Once assembled, the mower fired up and ran well! Aside from continuing to billow white smoke. =(

Looks like I didn't fix the seals that were broken or replaced the seals incorrectly. **End Update**

I believe the linkage here is correct. It appears that the bushing should fit in the large hole with the rod, but I haven't gotten it to fit (small spaces, big hands).

[image]

I am confident about the linkage at the second end of the rod. I saw an image of the motor of a matching model that looked like this:

[image]

So I suppose what I am uncertain about is if something else is hooked up incorrectly.

When I push either direction on the Governor lever, it moves about half an inch:

[image]

[image]

But if I move the throttle on the console, the Governor lever doesn't move at all. It's supposed to move, right? Or does it 'hang loose' unless the engine is running?

Here's the best picture I have from during disassembly. (It looks like the spring had fallen off, I don't know if that was because I was disassembling or if it fell off beforehand.)

[image]

How does the Governor bar going into the engine work?
Can I totally screw up my engine by allowing that to spin?
Should it be turned all the way to the left or right before tightening the Governor lever?
Now that the rod is connected (once I set the retaining clips/bushing) should I push the Governor lever all the way to the "drivers side" or "passenger side" before tightening?

[image: Parts schematic]
[image: Schematic legend]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is what it appears to me ...

First, you have the part numbered as "20", which is actually part 22. The grouped parts are 21 (spring), 22 (bushing), and 23 (throttle linkage).

22 should fit into the larger hole in the throttle (marked with red arrow). I'm not sure how 22 stays in the throttle end (hole), but there should be something there (unless the spring is used to keep it in place and it doesn't go into the hole with green arrow). The end of 21 (green circle) should go into the small hole (green arrow). The end of 23 should be able to slide back and forth in 22 while 21 keeps it at the end.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my parts. I made the connections as you suggested and provided a much bigger context of the assembly. The reason I felt something was wrong largely has to do with that the Governor Lever doesn't move when I adjust the throttle. But maybe it's not supposed to? Or maybe some of those big front springs are in the wrong place? (They currently match a picture of the same model mower and engine that I found online.)

Comment: You definitely answered my original question - thanks!